# Sort X most recent Firestore documents Ascending by timestamp, and add in real time

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to create a chat app using firestore. My message class has a timestamp in the form of a `Date` object. I would like the chat activity to load the most recent X messages, and add any new ones to the bottom in realtime using a `SnapshotListener`. Below is what I have so far, which sorts the X *oldest* messages by timestamp, but ignores all messages after and does not display any new messages when they are added if a full X messages are already pulled down.

```
 final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);


        Query query = mCollection.orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.ASCENDING).limit(mCurrentPage * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD);


        query.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                for (DocumentChange documentChange : queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                    switch (documentChange.getType()) {
                        case ADDED:
                            Message message = documentChange.getDocument().toObject(Message.class);



                            mMessages.add(message);
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Edit: I've removed superfluous code. Sorting by descending causes messages to be laid out like this when queried, with newest messages queried appearing at the top, which doesn't work, because I want newest messages at the bottom descending upward:

- queriedmessage5<-newest queried
- queriedmessage4
- queriedmessage3
- queriedmessage2
- queriedmessage1<-oldest queried
- newmessage1<-added after query

Reversing the RecyclerView using setReverseLayout via the layout manager corrects the order of the queried messages, but then inserts new messages at the top of the RecyclerView :

- newmessage1<-added after query
- queriedmessage1<-oldest queried
- queriedmessage2
- queriedmessage3
- queriedmessage4
- queriedmessage5<-newest queried

Comment: Your `onEvent` is supposed to be triggered whenever a new message is added (or the query results change in any other way). Is that not happening for you?

Comment: It is, but only if the number of messages in the collection is under the query's limit number. When that number of messages have been sent/downloaded, new messages only get sent to the collection and do not appear on screen when added.

Comment: Yeah, I see now. You'll need to order descending to allow that.

Comment: If you are interested, I have explained in one of my **[tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb)** how you can create a Chat App using the exact same query that you are looking for.

Comment: How did you solve the problem?

Comment: I added a boolean after the for loop that got switched when onEvent was first called, then had messages loaded thereafter enter the list at the other side.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to order the messages descending to be able to get the 10 most recent messages.

```
mCollection.orderBy("timestamp",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(mCurrentPage * TOTAL_ITEMS_TO_LOAD)
```

This will give you the most recent items. As you add messages, you'll get the newest ones, and you'll get a `REMOVED` event for the messages that fall out of the query.

Given that you request the messages in reverse chronological order, you'll have to reverse the message client side again, to show them in the correct order in your app.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. What do you mean by "reverse the messages client side?"  I've gone down a route where I've sorted descending and then set reverse layout on the RecyclerView housing it all (I want new messages to appear at the bottom), but then it adds messages to the top of the screen unless I insert a message at position 0 of the message list, which causes all new messages to appear with whatever the content of the message in that position was when the RecyclerView was created. Are you proposing something else?

Comment: I honestly can't understand what you've done from your description. If you've tried the approach I describe, update your question to show that, In general, I don't understand why you have a `if (itemPos == 1) {` in the handler. My minimal logic would be, "if the document is new, add it to the list".

Comment: Apologies. I've removed superfluous code and edited for clarity.